# ALIGN COLGROUP IN TABLE

Tags: html

```
<div id="temptable">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="background-color:#000000;color:white;">
                <th style="float:left;">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="0" year="0" onchange="selectElement(this);">
                </th>
                <th style="width:25px;" colspan="2">YEAR</th>
                <th>UNIT</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="background-color: #006400;">
                <th style="float:left;">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="0" year="2015" onchange="selectElement(this);">
                </th>
                <th colspan="2"><strong> 2015</strong>
                </th>
                <th onclick="dropdown(this);"><b>UNIT:&gt;&gt;</b>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="float:left;">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="11" year="2015">
                </td>
                <td style="width:25px;" colspan="2">1</td>
                <td><a href="paper/aptitude.pdf" target="_blanck"><img src="image/download.png"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="background-color: #006400;">
                <th style="float:left;">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="0" year="2014" onchange="selectElement(this);">
                </th>
                <th colspan="2"><strong> 2014</strong>
                </th>
                <th onclick="dropdown(this);"><b>UNIT:&gt;&gt;</b>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: none;">
                <td style="float:left;">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="7" year="2014">
                </td>
                <td style="width:25px;" colspan="2">1</td>
                <td><a href="paper/aptitude.pdf" target="_blanck"><img src="image/download.png"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="background-color: #006400;">
                <th style="float:left;">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="0" year="2013" onchange="selectElement(this);">
                </th>
                <th colspan="2"><strong> 2013</strong>
                </th>
                <th onclick="dropdown(this);"><b>UNIT:&gt;&gt;</b>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: none;">
                <td style="float:left;">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="6" year="2013">
                </td>
                <td style="width:25px;" colspan="2">1</td>
                <td><a href="paper/aptitude.pdf" target="_blanck"><img src="image/download.png"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="background-color: #006400;">
                <th style="float:left;">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="0" year="2011" onchange="selectElement(this);">
                </th>
                <th colspan="2"><strong> 2011</strong>
                </th>
                <th onclick="dropdown(this);"><b>UNIT:&gt;&gt;</b>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: none;">
                <td style="float:left;">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="12" year="2011">
                </td>
                <td style="width:25px;" colspan="2">1</td>
                <td><a href="paper/aptitude.pdf" target="_blanck"><img src="image/download.png"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: none;">
                <td style="float:left;">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="14" year="2011">
                </td>
                <td style="width:25px;" colspan="2">1</td>
                <td><a href="paper/aptitude.pdf" target="_blanck"><img src="image/download.png"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The table's width is 100%; I want checkbox and year show in left, and unit show in right; using `float` or `text-align` doesn't work properly.

Comment: Can You share Fiddle?

Comment: Can you explain why using `float` or `text-align` doesn't work properly? What's "wrong" about it?

Comment: You should also fix the spelling of "_blank" in <a href="paper/aptitude.pdf" target="_blanck">

Answer (score 0):

You should start by fixing your table format -  tags are not to wrap each row, but just the section below the header row (which should be wrapped in  tags).   is only for the first row of the table, within the  section  (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tbody.asp)

```
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>CHECKBOX</th>
         <th>YEARS</th>
         <th>UNITS</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>checkbox</td>
          <td>year</td>
          <td>unit</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>checkbox</td>
          <td>year</td>
          <td>unit</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>checkbox</td>
          <td>year</td>
          <td>unit</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```